# Cannibalistic Words

Tags: logical-deduction, english, no-computers, word-property, anagram

Drawing from the word pool below, find the twelve **Cannibalistic Words**.

<sub>(Note the [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) and [logical-deduction](/questions/tagged/logical-deduction) tags.)</sub>

---

1. WILD
   _ _ ☐ _ _ _ _ ☐
2. PENS
   ☐ _ _ _ _ ☐ _ _
3. DEED
   _ _ _ ☐ ☐ _ _ _
4. BLED
   _ _ ☐ _ _ _ _ ☐
5. MINI
   _ _ ☐ _ _ _ _ _
6. REED
   ☐ _ ☐ _ _ _ _ _
7. NEST
   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ☐
8. BRAT
   _ ☐ ☐ _ _ _ _ _
9. AUNT
   _ ☐ _ _ _ _ ☐ _
10. MEAD
    ☐ ☐ _ _ _ _ _ _
11. BARE
    _ _ _ ☐ _ _ ☐ _
12. COED
    _ ☐ _ _ _ ☐ _ _

Word Pool:
DISH, CATS, EACH, VIED, PORT, HOLY, SIGN, FLED, LIES, VOLT, BEER, EXES

---

Now answer the following question:

### What do Cannibalistic Words end up with?

Comment: Is *Cannibalistic words* a concept invented for this puzzle or some kind of common puzzle? If the second, could you explain how it works?

Comment: @Masclins The term was invented for this puzzle.

Comment: what are the squares meaning?

Comment: @Chowzen With another great puzzle! +1

Comment: I just noticed it says " find the ten Cannibalistic Words " when there are 12 pairs.  Is this a hint for the final answer or an error?

Comment: @TwoBitOperation Ha! Sorry, that was a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To solve:

> Each numbered word either takes in a word from the word pool, or is taken in by one to form an 8 letter word.  Then, note the letters in the boxes and anagram them.

Answers:

> 1. WILD + BEER = BEWILDER  -> **WR**
> 2. PENS + EXES = EXPENSES -> **ES**
> 3. DEED +  PORT = DEPORTED -> **OR**
> 4. BLED +  EACH =  BLEACHED -> **ED**
> 5. MINI + DISH = DIMINISH -> **M**
> 6. REED + VOLT= REVOLTED - > **RV**
> 7. NEST + HOLY = HONESTLY - > **Y**
> 8. BRAT + VIED = VIBRATED - > **IB**
> 9. AUNT + FLED =  FLAUNTED -> **LE**
> 10. MEAD + LIES = LIMEADES - > **LI**
> 11. BARE + CATS = CABARETS -> **AT**
> 12. COED +  SIGN =  COSIGNED ->  **ON**

Final letters:

> WRESOREDMRVYIBLELIATON

**What do Cannibalistic Words end up with?**

EDIT:  Thanks ***entirely*** to @Walt, the letters unscramble to:

> Irritable Vowel Syndrome

Comment: Let's dispense with the no-computers tag for the Anagram. I know that 22 letters is a bit much.

Comment: I've been at this for a while.  I feel like 22 letters gives too many options for an answer with no guidance on word count/ word length for the final phrase.

Comment: The checkmark is yours if you add the [final answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73642/cannibalistic-words/73674#73674). :)

Answer (score 7):

TwoBitOperation deserves most of the credit, I'll just provide the punny answer...

> WRESOREDMRVYIBLELIATON = Irritable Vowel Syndrome ;)

Comment: Nice! I was about to add a hint on number of words and number of letters/word, but now I don't have to. +1

Comment: I wasn't even close; good solve!